# What determines if a JavaScript function is a named anonymous function versus a, um, regular function?

Tags: javascript, syntax, semantics

Reading ["A re-introduction to JavaScript"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript#Functions) I noticed something interesting about functions:

> The name provided to an anonymous function as above is(or at least should be) only available to the function's own scope.

Entering some things based on the code in the tutorial at the nodejs prompt I was able to verify that node agrees with the author:

```
function add(foo, bar) {
  return foo + bar;
}

add(1, 2);
```

gets me 3, and:

```
var five = (function plus(foo, bar) {
             return foo + bar;
           })(2, 3);
plus(2, 3);
```

gets me a syntax error about plus not being defined.

I'm a little confused because the code I used to define both functions was identical (except for the name).  How does JavaScript know the first one is a regular function and the second one is a named anonymous function?

Comment: "named anonymous" :) It can't be both.

Comment: @pimvdb indeed.  It's actually a named function _expression_, not an anonymous function.

Comment: @pimvdb: LOL, I know, right? But that's what the article calls them.  I don't suppose you know what ECMA calls them?

Comment: @Samuel Edwin Ward: I believe it's a function declaration vs a function expression. The thing is that only function expressions can be anonymous. This is often the case in fact, and apparently they have (incorrectly) become synonyms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first is a normal function declaration.  The declared name is introduced into the current scope, and implicitly refers to the function body.  In this form, `function` is a *statement*, and as such returns no value.

The second is a *function expression*, and the interpreter knows that because it's part of the right hand side of an assignment, and because of the braces around it.  Any time the word `function` appears where some other "value" (or "expression") could have been supplied then what you have is a function expression.  The *result* of that expression is a reference to the function body.

The name of a function expression (if it were given one) is only available *within* the function, as described in your link.

IMHO the nomenclature in that link is incorrect.  What they call a "named anonymous functions" should in my view just be called a "named function expression".  This apparent error may stem from the fact that all anonymous functions are actually function expressions, but not all function expressions are anonymous.

Note that if you use this style:

```
var foo = function bar() {
    ...
}
```

then as described above `bar` is a function expression, whose result is then assigned to the variable `foo`.  The name `bar` is not put into the current scope, but is available within the function itself.

The declaration of the variable `foo` will be hoisted to the top of the scope, but will not be assigned its value (i.e. the reference to the function expression) until the line above is actually executed.

Another interesting demonstration of the difference is this (from the Chrome console):

```
> function() { }
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
> a = function() { }
function () { }
```

Note that the only difference is that in the latter there is an assignment to `a`.  The attempt to declare an anonymous function using a *statement* is illegal, because the language grammar requires that the function statement include a label for the function.  However the latter is implicitly a function expression, which is allowed to be anonymous.

Comment: I've already upvoted this answer because it demonstrates a clear knowledge of the subject at hand and a not unremarkable skill at explaining it.  I also agree that the phrase "named anonymous function" is an oxymoron.  The example of (the value of) a "named function expression" being assigned to a variable of another name is very nice at explaining what is going on here.  But I still feel at a loss as to the why (or perhaps the how). [continued]

Comment: "because it's part of the right hand side of an assignment, and because of the braces around it."  I assume by "braces" you mean ASCII 40 and 41?  Is your explanation necessary and sufficient?  Can you cite chapter and verse?  If I were to provide the code in question as an argument in a function call, without parentheses, and without assigning it to a variable, would it be a function declaration or a named function expression?

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard that would also be a function expression.  In general _only_ the syntax  `function foo() { ... }` is a normal function declaration, the hint being the `function` token being the first thing in the statement.  Pretty much anything else is a function expression.  I think the oxymoronic part results from all anonymous functions actually being function expressions, but not all function expressions are anonymous.

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard ultimately it all comes down to the language grammar.  A function declaration does exactly what it says, and no more.It introduces the variable into the scope.  But any time you type the word `function` in a place where a value (i.e. an expression) is expected then implicitly it's a function expression.  Since the contents of `()` must be an expression, any function therein is a function expression.

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard I think you may be looking for this: http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13