# Javascript; functions created by assigning to a variable?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

Wanted to get some input on this. When writing Javascript, I'm used to creating functions like this:

```
function firstThing() {
    console.log("first");
};
```

I was following a tutorial, and saw this setup. Using a variable assignment, and then passing an anonymous function, which then... becomes the function name. Is there a reason this would be used instead of the "traditional" way above?

```
var secondThing = function() {
    console.log("second");
};
```

Calling them is the same:

```
firstThing()
secondThing()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called a function expression:

```
var foo = function() {}
```

and this is a function declaration:

```
function foo() {}
```

A major difference is that function declarations are "hoisted". Behind the scenes, a function declaration is "hoisted" to the top of its scope and assigned to a variable name - effectively the same as a function expression.

Consider this:

```
foo(); //logs 'abc'
function() {
  console.log('abc');
}
```

That works fine because `foo` will be hoisted. With a function expression, this will fail:

```
foo(); //foo is not defined!
var foo = function() {
  console.log('abc');
}
```

One thing that's awesome about function expressions is that you can assign their value with an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) and have private values and functions like this:

```
var myFunc = (function() {
  function thisWillBeMyFunc() {
    doOne();
    doTwo();
    doThree();
  }

  function doOne() {
    console.log('Action 1!');
  }
  function doTwo() {
    console.log('Action 2!');
  }
  function doThree() {
    console.log('Action 3!');
  }

  return thisWillBeMyFunc;
}());

myFunc(); //logs the actions

doOne(); //error - not defined!
```

**[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/OpEwoKAZ/1/edit)**

Oh, the wonderful power and flexibility of JavaScript!

Comment: I remember I've read a wonderful article one day but at this moment I cannot find anything better than http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-2-variable-object/#entering-the-execution-context --- and actually it states that I'm wrong. So seems like I confused something hmmmmmmm. And that's weird because what I was reading that article that I cannot found - it was a strong distinction between those 2 steps. So, yes, seems like it **IS** hoisting and I was thinking wrong for long ago :-S

Comment: I know this was marked as a duplicate but I appreciate the discussion / examples. Just for fun:
http://jsfiddle.net/8UTFD/3/
http://jsfiddle.net/8UTFD/4/

Answer (score 1):

There is another difference. The first creates a named function, the second option will create an anonymous function.

When you are viewing the stack trace the second option will appear as an anonymous function the first will appear named. You can see how the first approach would give you some insight when debugging.

Some further references [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081593/are-named-functions-or-anonymous-functions-preferred-in-javascript) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081088/what-determines-if-a-javascript-function-is-a-named-anonymous-function-versus-a).

Comment: What is your preferred method(s) to view the stack trace in Javascript?